# making a custom page template

Tags: theming, 7

I currently have a general template and a front page template. I made a custom node for a content type I made and it works just fine but then realized that I need an entirely new page template as well. I already made a page--[content_name].tpl.php file and cleared the cache but it wasn't read. Is there something I need to change elsewhere or is what I'm doing completely off? Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more detail like the content type name and tpl file name. Just for trying go to theme setting and save the theme again. It might work.

Comment: create a tpl file in your theme folder, as nodetype.tpl.php as if you have created a node type article them create a templete as article.tpl.php. and this will works, i have used this way in d6,

Comment: content type is events_home and the filename used was pages--events_home.tpl.php.

Comment: tried making a tpl file that way. it didn't work.

Comment: its page--events_home.tpl.php not "pages" use "page"

Comment: sorry, that s wasn't supposed to be there. in any case, it turned out there was a modification in template.php that had to be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Drupal 6 -- `page-[content_type_name].tpl.php` and clear the cache.

For Drupal 7 -- http://www.digett.com/blog/01/11/2012/overriding-page-templates-content-type-drupal-7

Comment: isn't that for Drupal 6? tried it out and it didn't work.

Comment: Oh sry I didn't notice this. Checkout this article http://www.digett.com/blog/01/11/2012/overriding-page-templates-content-type-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing. means a different layout for specific content type using panels. Check the first answer : [Panels for Node Types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20647/panels-for-node-types)

Comment: there isn't a Structures->Pages section in the admin.

Comment: You need to install panels and pages module.